# Processos - Dúvida

Tags: c, linux, processo

Para melhor entender o funcionamento dos processos, fork, escrevi este programa teste:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   int value = 9 ;
   int pid = fork();

   if(pid==0) value+=2 ;
       else  value-=5 ;

   printf("%d",value);
}
```

O output obtido foi

```
411
```

Não era bem isto o que esperava.

- afinal quanto vale a variável value?
- o que é ao certo que está a acontecer?

Answer (score 1):

Depois do `fork()` (se nao houve erro) ha duas variaveis distintas com nome `value`. Uma esta no processo original (com valor `9`), outra esta no processo filho (tambem com valor `9`).

o `if (pid == 0)` faz coisas diferentes no 2 processos activos. Num deles aumenta `2` ao seu `valor` e no outro diminui `5` ao outro `valor`.

Depois os dois processos escrevem a sua variavel, sem haver requerimento da ordem pela qual se faz essa escrita.

Um dos processos tem `valor` com 4 (9 - 5), outro tem 11 (9 + 2).

Tanto 411 como 114 sao resultados perfeitamente aceitaveis.